# How to increase the value for items within foreach - Powershell (IIS)

Tags: powershell, iis

I have a little script to set up the value for the recycling time for some app pools. The thing is that I have around 190 items and I rather to use a script than do it manually.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

#Getting all the AppPools
$pools = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools
$RestartTime = @("05:00", "15:00")


ForEach ($pool in $pools) 
{
    $app_pool = $pool.name

    # Delete all existing scheduled recycle items
    # Clear-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$app_pool -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule

    # Checking the actual value
    Write-Host $app_pool
    (Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\\AppPools\$app_pool -name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection) | select value

    # Set the application pool to recycle at the time we want
    # New-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$app_pool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value=$RestartTime}

}
```

I want to restart all app pools at 5:00am and 3:00pm but increasing the specific time for a specific group of app pools within those times. i.e:

- App pool 1-20: 5:00am and 3:00pm
- App pool 21-40: 5:10am and 3:10pm
- App pool 41-60: 5:20am and 3:20pm

I'm completely stuck in that part and I don't know how to do it

Can someone throw me some help here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a conditional with a counter for the loop, here is my idea

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

#Getting all the AppPools
$pools = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools
$RestartTime = @("05:00", "15:00")

$count = 0
ForEach ($pool in $pools) 
{
    $app_pool = $pool.name

    # Delete all existing scheduled recycle items
    # Clear-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$app_pool -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule

    if ($count -le 20){
        $RestartTime = @("05:00", "15:00")
    }
    elseif ($count -gt 20 -and $count -le 40) {
        $RestartTime = @("05:10", "15:10")
    } else {
        $RestartTime = @("05:20", "15:20")
    }
    $count++

    # Checking the actual value
    Write-Host $app_pool
    (Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\\AppPools\$app_pool -name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection) | select value

    # Set the application pool to recycle at the time we want
    # New-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$app_pool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value=$RestartTime}

}
```